# Implement Push Service on premise for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

Is there a way to implement a push service for Windows Phone on premise or is the Azure service the only option to implement push notifications for Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own service (WebAPI or WCF) for receiving the Push Notification URLS (those urls look like http://something.notify.live.net/thirdparty/uniqueId) and are provided by the Push Notification Capability which you need to enable in your WPManifest.

Once you want to send the push notification, send the XML template to the collection of urls.

More information can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202970%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Jeff Blankenburg can also help you out with [a working demo](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/19/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-19-push-notifications/) which you can download.